# sql query problem

Tags: sql, oracle

why this query give me an error:ORA-01790

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(logical_date,'MM') MONTH
       FROM logical_date WHERE logical_date_type='B'        
UNION 
SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(logical_date,'MM')+1 MONTH
        FROM logical_date WHERE logical_date_type='B'
```

but when i run them separately,they give the proper output.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to "add 1" to a string. TO_CHAR returns a string, so +1 will cause an implicit type conversion to a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the `+1` is causing a data type conversion. Try:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(logical_date,'MM')+0 MONTH 
       FROM logical_date WHERE logical_date_type='B'         
UNION  
SELECT  
        TO_CHAR(logical_date,'MM')+1 MONTH 
        FROM logical_date WHERE logical_date_type='B'
```

Answer (score 3):

You want a distinct set of months in this table, plus all their following months, right?

```
select to_char(logical_date, 'MM') MONTH 
from (   
    SELECT logical_date
    FROM logical_date WHERE logical_date_type='B'        
    UNION 
    SELECT ADD_MONTHS(logical_date,1)
    FROM logical_date WHERE logical_date_type='B'
)
/
```

Alternatively we can use `TRUNC(logical_date, 'MM')` to retrieve the first day of the month, should we need to retain a DATE datatype.